# ". filename" can't find file when run from /bin/sh, works from /bin/bash; why?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

My simple script is like this:

```
#!/bin/sh


DEF=.file_name_with_a_leading_dot.sh

. ${DEF}
```

Notice the /bin/sh on the top line.
When I run that simple script I get an error that the file isn't found.
But, if I change that top line to #!/bin/bash then the script finds that file in the current directory just fine.

But, On my Ubuntu linux laptop I see that /bin/sh is a symlink to /bin/bash . So, why does my script behave differently?

Also, I can run the script like this:

```
/bin/bash ./script.sh
```

And it's OK.

So, what am I missing?

Comment: You can have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash. Basically, `bash` and `sh` are not the same thing

Comment: Bash starts in compatibility mode when called as `/bin/sh`

Comment: But why does that mean it doesn't find the file?  I can reproduce this.

Comment: sh mode seems to work differently ./.file works.....

Comment: Please keep in mind, when writing a question title, that the goal of StackOverflow is to build a knowledgebase -- we probably have *hundreds* of questions about compatibility differences between bash and POSIX sh, so for a question to be something folks can actually find and distinguish when searching in that knowledgebase, it needs to have a title that reflects the *specific* difference it's asking about. I've tried to edit accordingly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [Manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sh):

> **. filename [arguments]**
>
> **source filename [arguments]** Read and execute
> commands from filename in the current shell environment and return the
> exit status of the last command executed from filename. **If filename
> does not contain a slash, file names in PATH are used to find the
> directory containing filename.** The file searched for in PATH need not
> be executable. **When bash is not in posix mode, the current directory
> is searched if no file is found in PATH.** If the sourcepath option to
> the shopt builtin command is turned off, the PATH is not searched. If
> any arguments are supplied, they become the positional parameters when
> filename is executed. Otherwise the positional parameters are
> unchanged. The return status is the status of the last command exited
> within the script (0 if no commands are executed), and false if
> filename is not found or cannot be read.

So, it seems that the shebang `#!/bin/sh` sets your bash to posix mode. In this mode, only `PATH` is evaluated, not the current directory.

Comment: Which means: use `. ./"$DEF"` to make it work in POSIX mode.